# What's the best way to display a section of a document on a page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-viewer-web-part

I have a massive employee guide that resides in a controlled documents site. Much of the content contained in the guide will need to be displayed in different sections across various different sites. Is there a way to embed different sections of the document on different sites such that they update automatically based on changes made to the controlled document? Can a page viewer webpart be told to display a section of a document rather than the entire document? I'm working with sharepoint online (2013).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this could be achieved out of the box in SharePoint 2013 online.  Using OpenXML and custom code you may be able to create web parts that display certain sections of a document on a page.

Alternatively you could break the document into sections and then use open XML to construct a documented formed from the various parts.

Each section could be maintained as a Wiki page (for example) and then a word document could be built by putting the pages together - there is an example of this technique here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956524%28office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This seems like a very good suggestion.